# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function search() on null

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysqli and only fimiliar some with php.  I was doing a tutorial and came across this error in my code. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function search() on null in Search.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main}.  Can anyone explain what I am looking for to correct this error? It does connect to the database I just changed the bottom connect info for online purposes.

Here is the code in my search.php and below that the class-search.php

```
 <?php


 $search_results=""; 

//Check if search data was submitted
if ( isset( $_GET['s'])){

    //Include the search class
    require( dirname(_FILE_) . '/classes/class-search.php');

    //Instantiate a new instance of search class
    $search_term - new search();

    //Store search term into a variable
    $search_term = $_GET['s'];

    //Send the search term to our search class and store result
    $search_results = $search->search($search_term);

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search</h1>
<div class="search-form">
<form action="" method="GET">
<div class="form-field">
<label for="search-field">Search</label>
<input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Enter your search term" results="5" value="<?php echo 
$search_term; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Search">    

</div>
</form>
</div>

<?php if( $search_results) : ?>

<div class ="results-count">
    <p><?php echo $search_results['count']; ?> results found</p>
</div>

<div class="results-table">
        <?php foreach ( $search_results['results'] as $search_result ) : ?>
        <div class="result">
        <p><?php echo $search_result->name; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<div class="search-raw">
<pre><?php print_r($search_results); ?></pre>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the class-search.php

```
<?php 

class search{

//mysqli connection
private $mysqli;


//constructure that sets up the class
public function __construct() {
    //Connect to our database and store in $mysqli property
    $this->connect();   
}

//Database connection ths connects to our database
private function connect() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli( '$host_name', '$user_name', '$password', '$database );


//Performs the search
public function search($search_term){
    //sanitizes the search term to prevent injection attacks
    $sanitized = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);

    //run the query
    $query = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM Simple WHERE name LIKE '{$sanitized}%'");


    //Check Results
    if( ! $query->num_rows) {
        return false;
    }


    //Loop and fetch data
    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ){
        $rows[] =$row;
    }


    //Build and return results

    $search_results = array(
        'count'=> $query->num_rows,
        'results' => $rows,
    );

    return $search_results;

    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Where do you define the `$search` variable?  Also, you have a syntax error in your `search` class which would prevent that from being parsed at all.  The syntax highlighting on this Stack Overflow question shows you where the typo is (unclosed quotes).

Comment: I apologize on this but are you talking about the unclosed quote after the database in the function connect?  or in the public function search?  I am sorry about asking these been working on this for two days and my eyes are not seeing this.

Comment: This one: `new mysqli( '$host_name', '$user_name', '$password', '$database )`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I found where my mistake was in the search.php

Comment: changed this //Instantiate a new instance of search class
    $search_term - new search(); to $search = new search();  again thank you so much.